# Identify network device from IP, MAC or Hostname

Tags: c#

I've been looking for a way to get a list of PCs in the network (Hostnames). Looking here and elsewhere i found lots of mentions using `DirectoryEntry` but none of them worked for me (I get an empty list).

Finally here at SO i found an answer - get the ARP table using `GetIpNetTable`.

That got me IPs and MAC addresses. With the IPs i got the Hostname using `Dns.GetHostEntry`. However now my list has PCs, Printers, Routers and anything else connected on the LAN at the moment of search.

How can I filter out this devices to keep only PCs (Desktops and Laptops)?

Any other solution to get the list of PCs that works will also be accepted.

Comment: "Printers, Routers and anything else connected on the LAN" are computers. Yes. Really.

Comment: Just because it doesn't have a monitor and keyboard doesn't mean its not a computer. Many of your devices even run Linux.

Comment: @spender Funny haha (not) - I know all that - even a phone is a computer - still my question stands - how can i identify the device type

Comment: @RonBeyer - see my comment above

Comment: @537mfb You can't identify a device type given an IP, host name, or MAC address. Sometimes you can use a MAC to identify the *manufacturer of the network card/chip* but nothing about an IP/name/MAC says its one device or another. You can try port probing or packet scanning and "guessing" the device type but its unreliable. There is nothing you can universally send to an IP and it responds back with "I'm a XYZ".

Comment: You can try an snmp (simple network management protocol) call and if it response you will know what it is, but if you get no answer it remains unknown.

Comment: @RonBeyer I figured as much :( but all i could find so far to map a network only gets me that far. Are there any options that you know of for me to get what i need? (hostnames of PCs only - Desktops or Laptops) - Windows does so there must be a way

Comment: @DieterMeemken Will look into SNMP and see if it leads anywhere